# How to deal with "Unexpected token (X:Y)" messages in pug?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I am getting this error in pug:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (69:1)
  ... ridiculous stacktrace here
```

I could post my code here and someone would fix it for me. But can you instead tell how to understand this error? I assumed that `69:1` means `line:column`, but my code 27 lines.

In case you don't trust me here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <meta name="author" content="Jakub Mareda">
  <title>#{title}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    p Logged in probably. Or whatever. Why is Express so complicated?

    <!--
      table
        thead
          tr
            each entryName, i in headers
              th #{entryName}
        tbody
          each user, i in users
            tr
              td 
                a(href='/admin/post/' + post.id) #{post.author} - #{post.title}
                -->
    pre #{data}
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that it was **my intent** to comment out most of the code.

But just telling me what to change is not an answer to this question. Explaining the error code and telling me how to handle it next time is.

Comment: I reduced the comment to just `<!-- \n comment \n -->` (replacing \n with an actual new line, which don't come out in code comments on SO) and it threw the same error. Maybe pug doesn't actually support block comments like it says it does?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan No idea. I ended up moving the code in other file. I also tried to comment out using `//` as pug command (all I wanted commented was indented 2 more spaces than `//`). Didn't work either. My main concern here is that I've seen people getting all kinds of Unexpected token (X:X) messages. The error is utterly unhelpful, so I am looking for guidance how to debug it in general. For start - what do those numbers even mean?